# fast VNC server on Linux

Tags: linux, performance, vnc

How can I make my VNC server on a Linux machine fast as possible (without trading off security) (and connecting to an already running X session)?

I'm running a VNC server (x11vnc) on my Ubuntu and I occasionally connect to it from another Ubuntu machine over LAN.

```
x11vnc -localhost -usepw -ncache 10 -forever -display :0
```

I use above command and SSH port forwarding. I connect with this (xtightvncviewer):

```
vncviewer -encodings 'copyrect tight hextile' localhost:0
```

Connecting to an already running X session is important. If that were not case, I'd use NX or SSH X11 forwarding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TightVNC over SSH has a decent reputation for speed. I don't know if you're going to notice a lot of difference among different implementations though.

Answer (score 4):

try [nomachine](http://www.nomachine.com/) or its free / gpl implementation [free nx](http://freenx.berlios.de/). you'll not think about vnc twice after you switch.

Comment: With NX, you can either attach to a new X session which is really fast, or attach to an already running X session which is slow.

Answer (score 1):

If you can trade quality of picture for reactivity, try to lower the picture quality.

I use these parameters, but have not checked them with most recent x11vnc releases.

```
vncviewer $IP -bgr233 -compresslevel 9 -encodings "tight"
```

or

```
vncviewer $IP -bgr233 -quality 0 -encodings "tight"
```